Using «sudo chmod -R ugo+xwr /» and now trying a repair / Update: How do I get access to the core system with another computer
I gonna try to be brief : «Recently» I decide to mount a server computer, mostly because we have several computer at home and I was thinking it may be a good idea. So, for that matter, I choose to use Ubuntu server.
And, after a while, when I try to give everyone's permission to a new folder, my finger slip on «enter» before I finish and there I am.
You can say it, I'm clumsy.
With that mistake at hand, and after reading some people here and there having similar issues, it appear that the only way I have to repair my mistake will be to... repair the boot with a flashdrive.
'Thing is, the only option I have was for «install», no re-install or, be foolish, repair.
And the only option I have is not a good one... I don't want to loose all the data.
Or... maybe I can take the main drive of my server, connect it to my computer and recover everything? That may be the simplest way of doing...
Anyway, I leave my question even if it work, because I want to know how to «re-install», or why that option disappear.
It may be useful.
Update : I plug my server main drive on my PC and I got access to my solid drive, but not to the core system of it.
How can I get access to the core?

You have broken your system beyond repair. You have lost the carefully designed permission structure that used to let your system work.  Attach the disk to a working system, copy your  use data, then reinstall. This could be made easier by having /home on it's own partition, seperate from / everything else. Then, the next time you reinstall, you can tell the installer not to format that partition.

BTW, Don't Do That!  The Unix/Linux way is to type carefully, and consider the consequences, especially when using sudo. Don't commit UTBLT! (Using Tool Before Learning Tool) (Using Thing Before Learning Thing).

I take note of it, @vidarlo, mostly for all the tricks to avoid that kind of problem. Right now, my only wish is to keep my data.  Anyhow, I've update the main post.

What @waltinator wrote - boot from a live medium and copy your data, and reinstall.

I saw it, @vidarlo. The problem : I only got access to 2.1GB of 1TB of my server main drive.
And I don't know how to get access to all the data without corrupting them.

Then I'd create a question focusing on that, describing what you see from the live environment and how things are configured. We don't know what hard drives and mount points you used, so you have to tell us :)

Does this answer your question? How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels? The intention of this duplicate link is to instruct you how to chroot into your system from an Ubuntu live USB session so that you can run commands on it.
